# Filtering pandas exactly by pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a data frame by whether or not one the columns has a word in a string, I have tried the following:

```
text="Abacus and androgeny and for"
tokenized = tknzr.tokenize(text.lower())
pattern= "|".join(tokenized)
lexicon = lexicon[lexicon["English (en)"].str.match(pattern, na = False)]
```

This does not actually work because words starting with "for" like forgery get matched. To be clear I want only rows that have exact matches to one of the words in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are only using match to determine if the word in the column is one of the words in the text?
If so - I'd try:

```
lexicon = lexicon[lexicon["English (en)"].isin(tokenized)]
```

This way the matches will be on the exact words, because it will compare it to the list of words.

Comment: This works perfectly don't know why I got so stuck in trying to use match, thanks a lot.